# Not able to creat folder and file via code in j2me

Tags: java-me

I am trying to create a folder and a image in j2me via code. I am able to creat a image file in Emulator, but when I tried to run that code in mobile(Nokia 2700)...it is giving exception. My code is as folloes.....

```
 Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
                String root = null;
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                root = (String) e.nextElement();
                break;
            }

 String  newFilePath = "file:///"+root+fileName[i];

 FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection) Connector.open(newFilePath,
 Connector.READ_WRITE);

                if(!fileConnection.exists())
                    fileConnection.create();

                else if(fileConnection.fileSize() == mediaSize){
                    fileConnection.close();
                    continue;
                }
```

What should I do for creat a image file in previously  exist folder, or if possible, how could I creat a folder in j2me.

Answer (score 0):

Some phones only allow creation of folders and files in certain subfolder(s) of root. You may not be allowed to create a folder or file in root on the Nokia 2700.

Typically, you have to go to the "Other" folder on these phones. So try one of these two for path and filename:

```
file:///c:/other/myfolder/myimage.jpg
file:///e:/other/myfolder/myimage.jpg
```

Depending on whether you want to save to the phone memory (drive c) or a memory card (drive e).